# XSLT: insert parameter value inside of an html attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, umbraco

How can I insert the youtubeId parameter in the following code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:YouTube="urn:YouTube"
    xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library YouTube">


<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="videoId"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
 <a href="{$videoId}">{$videoId}</a>

<object width="425" height="355">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/{$videoId}&amp;hl=en"></param>
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/{$videoId}&amp;hl=en" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="425" height="355"></embed>
</object>$videoId {$videoId} {$videoId}
 <xsl:value-of select="/macro/videoId" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`<xsl:value-of select="/macro/videoId" />` actually outputs the videoId but all other occurences do not.

I am creating a macro in Umbraco CMS. The parameter is correctly passed into the XSLT (because  actually outputs its value). **How can I insert this value into the src-attribute?**

Comment: How does your input document look like? And what environment/code/tool do you use to call your XSLT? Is the `videoId` an external parameter or is it contained in your input XML document?

Comment: I am creating a macro in Umbraco CMS. The parameter is correctly passed into the XSLT (because <xsl:value-of select="/macro/videoId" /> actually outputs its value). I just want to insert the value into the src-attribute. I dont care at all how I do that. Any workaround appreciated.

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution. :)

Comment: Don't confuse the external parameter with values in your input document. Your external parameter can be accessed using `$videoId` whereas `/macro/videoId` is a path in the input document. Those two are different!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> ```
>  <a href="{$videoId}">{$videoId}</a>
> ```

You must use `<xsl:value-of select="$videoId"/>` here:

```
<a href="{$videoId}"><xsl:value-of select="$videoId"/></a>
```

Whenever You are using an AVT (`{$videoId}`) inside an attribute value this must work with the exception of any `select` attribute.

In the last case you can use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/macro/*[name()=$videoId]" />
```

**When all of these are reflected in your transformation, it works in all cases**:

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:YouTube="urn:YouTube"
    xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library YouTube">


<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="videoId" select="'XXX'"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
 <a href="{$videoId}"><xsl:value-of select="$videoId"/></a>

<object width="425" height="355">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/{$videoId}&amp;hl=en"></param>
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/{$videoId}&amp;hl=en" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="425" height="355"></embed>
</object><xsl:value-of select="concat($videoId, ' ', $videoId, ' ', $videoId)"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="/macro/*[name()=$videoId]" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good answer (as always), and AVT is the term for *attribute value template*, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates (just for clarification ;-)

Comment: Your solution made me realize that the parameter videoId gets *not* set by umbraco. I modified it like this and it works: <xsl:param name="videoId" select="/macro/videoId"/>

Answer (score 1):

You may want to just get a package that helps with this as well.

http://our.umbraco.org is awesome and packages are being added all the time.

A quick search reveals a few options:

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/tag/youtube#projectList